# Load multiple external textures with WWW class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, ienumerator

I want to load multiple png files at runtime using Unity. I am using www class to load the textures with given directory. Here is my code:

```
    public IEnumerator LoadPNG(string _path)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(_path);
        foreach (string fileDir in filePaths)
        {
            using (WWW www = new WWW("file://" + Path.GetFullPath(fileDir )))
            {
                yield return www;
                Texture2D texture = Texture2D.whiteTexture;
                www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
                this.textureList.Add(texture);
            }
        }
    }
```

This function is called as coroutine. When the program finish the loading all textures, textureList array has correct amount of textures. But all of them are last loaded texture. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: with this line (Texture2D texture = Texture2D.whiteTexture;) you always set your reference to the same object. you have to initialise a new texture. I think with (new Texture2D) it will work

Comment: You can't directly say new Texture2D in unity without a resource. I already write over texture variable by LoadImageIntoTexture texture. So it shouldn't be a problem I think.

Comment: @mcelik You can use `new` keyword with `Texture2D` and I think this is your problem since you updated your code. `Texture2D texture =  new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);`

Comment: You both are right. Sorry I jumped into the answer without enough knowledge. Using new Texture2D solved the problem. But I couldn't get why it worked ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were doing small mistake with using only one object:

```
            using (WWW www = new WWW("file://" + Path.GetFullPath(fileDir )))
            {
                yield return www;
                // Change this...
                //Texture2D texture = Texture2D.whiteTexture;
                // to this:
                Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(0, 0);
                //or us this:
                //Texture2D texture = www.texture;
                www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
                textureList.Add(texture);
            }
```

As Dr. Fre also stated in comments.

Comment: With the current code in his question now, this is the solution.

Comment: Right, this is the solution. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake here: `using (WWW www = new WWW("file://" + Path.GetFullPath(_path)))`.

You are supposed to be using the `url` from the `foreach` loop which is `fileDir`.

**EDIT**:

Also move `textureList = new List<Texture2D>();` outside the function. Put it inside the `Start()` function or something.

```
    public IEnumerator LoadPNG(string _path)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(_path);
        foreach (string fileDir in filePaths)
        {
            using (WWW www = new WWW("file://" + Path.GetFullPath(fileDir)))
            {
                yield return www;
                Texture2D texture = Texture2D.whiteTexture;
                www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
                textureList.Add(texture);
            }
        }
    }
```

*Note*: It is recommended to loop over `List` with `for` loop instead of `foreach` loop in Unity. You don't have to worry about this in Unity 5.5.

Comment: My mistake. My working code is using fileDir. But wrote it wrong in the question :/ It is edited now.

Comment: @mcelik Look at edit. Move `textureList = new Dictionary<Texture2D>();` outside the `LoadPNG` function. Also, I think there is another typo in your question. Isn't `textureList = new Dictionary<int, Texture2D>();` suppose to be `textureList = new List<Texture2D>();`? If not, then `textureList.Add(texture);` should not compile. Please fix that in your question....Always try to put your code as it is to prevent issues like this in your question.

Comment: Latest edited version of the code will be more clear for the question. Thank you.